# 'RPPreviewViewControllerDelegate' is unavailable: not available on iOS

Tags: ios, xcode

I started getting the following error after updating from Xcode 7 to Xcode 8:

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/ReplayKit.framework/Headers/RPPreviewViewController.h:25:42:
>   'RPPreviewViewControllerDelegate' is unavailable: not available on iOS

The error comes from importing GameKit/Gamekit.h.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be that my project's iOS Deployment Target was set to 3.0. When I changed the iOS Deployment Target to 6.0, the error went away.

(More specifically, it was a library project.  Also, I had to edit the project file in a text editor to change the deployment target to 6 since this is not an option in the Xcode 8 GUI.)